# How does Windows execute assembly programs?

Tags: windows, assembly, operating-system, executable

I am starting to learn the assembly programming language and want to know how does Windows execute assembly programs? Does Windows also use the same procedures for executing .exe files?

At this point I am having a hard time focusing on learning the assembly programming language while constantly thinking of what happens in the background.

I am also looking for a book to get a better and deeper understanding of Windows internals and how general operating systems perform tasks such as the one stated above. Any help(terminology used to describe the procedure) or reference to external resources is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A native executable contains machine code, which can be executed by the CPU directly. The operating system essentially just loads it into memory, sets up a new process, and starts that process running at the start of the program.

Answer (score 7):

After you assemble your program, it becomes a normal executable, and Windows executes it like it would any other native executable.

Comment: I would add that assembly programs are not run themselves, they have to assembled before they can be run.